# From Coarse to Fine Collision Detection - Multiple Collisions on Same Object

Tags: c++, data-structures, collision-detection, physics, simulation

I'm currently working on a **collision detection algorithm** with a broad phase to detect possible collisions and a fine phase to do deterministic resolution of collisions. The **broad phase** is based on a hierarchical hash grid and is performing well.

The **fine phase** is based on a custom algorithm and is working with **n-body collisions**. In order to accurately resolve more than 2-body collisions, I will however need to somehow register all collisions and the corresponding elements in collision sets.

What would be the best way to **save collisions** in some way during the broad phase in order to **iterate through the collisions sets** in the fine phase? I was thinking along the lines of certain data structures, but I couldn't come up with an ideal solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My current approach**

After thinking about the problem a bit longer, I decided to try the following approach.

- collision sets are vectors of elements
- the collision sets themselves are stored in a list
- every element points to its collision set in a hashmap

If a collision is now detected during the broad phase:

1. If neither element is a key in the hashmap:

   - a new vector is created for the collision set
   - both elements are added to the collision set
   - the collision set is added to the collision list
   - both elements are inserted into the hashmap as key to the collision set
2. If one element is a key in the hashmap:

   - the collision set is retrieved through that element
   - the other element is added to the collision set
   - the other element is inserted into the hashmap as a key to the collision set
3. If both elements are a key in the hashmap:

   - if they are both pointing to the same collision set, it's OK
   - if they point to different collision sets

     - create new collision set vector
     - copy both collision sets into new colision set
     - remove both collision sets from collision list
     - add new collision set to collision list
     - iterate through new collision set and update reference in hashmap for each element

In the fine phase, I can now simply iterate over all collision sets in the collision list and do exact collision resolution.

The solution is rather fast, but I'm a bit worried about the memory foot print. I will have to do a couple of benchmarks to know more.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that paper's technique is applicable to performance-critical situations.

It seems like the technique is trying to solve the scenario where one object could "teleport" to the other side of a different object without colliding since moving objects in a simulation are typically just repositioned in each iteration.

I would suggest instead extruding each object across whatever space it traveled since the last update.  A box moving up would become a taller box, for example.

You could then detect potential collisions quickly without having to even consider motion or even the update rate for that matter.  Potential collisions could then be scrutinized as you like.

Comment: Again, this is not a question about the broad phase of collision detection, so you completely missed the point. You are also wrong as far as performance is concerned; if you read through point 4 of the paper (benchmarks), you will see that in their simulation - which is very similar to my scenario - their solution performs brilliantly in comparison to other popular methods. As I wrote, the broad phase collision detection is performing great.

Comment: @awishformore - It does look like you are asking for approaches to "detect all collisions in the broad phase".  Perhaps your question could be rephrased.

Comment: Hey. I slightly rephrased most of the post so even people skimming it can't pick up the wrong thing ;).